# Save image as… using alt text in Firefox

Tags: firefox, images

I'm saving images on different pages, and I'd prefer to use the alt text associated to the images as file names instead of the default file name (which doesn't mean anything at times.)

So how do I "Save image as…" `alt text.ext` automatically?

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the image, and click `view image info`.

Select the text and copy it. Now click on Save AS, paste in the name and click Save.

This of course assumes that there is alt text present.

Comment: I know how to do that. I want to skip all these steps obviously…

Comment: Maybe your question should state that then? http://superuser.com/posts/510776/edit

Answer (score 0):

I know you're using firefox but I couldn't find one that'd work very well.  There's an extension for chrome called Pendule.  Among other features, it has the ability to show the text of the alt text, there's also a more detailed features that grabs all images on one pages and displays information about each image.  Check out the pics and see if it's something that'd work for what you want.  I know it's not firefox, but it's a solution that'd be quicker than mousing over each image for instance.  You can get it here:

[Extension Link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pendule/gbkffbkamcejhkcaocmkdeiiccpmjfdi)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I too had this same scenario. After some internet search i found no extension that can do it. So, i made forked Open Source chrome extension "[Image Downloader](https://github.com/vdsabev/image-downloader)", and made some changes to do precisely that: Use the image's alt-text as the filename. You can check it out here: https://github.com/sansagara/image-downloader. You can clone the project and then install it from chrome by enabling developer mode.

I hope you find it as useful as it was for me!